# Individual Email Results incomplete

Tags: marketing-cloud

We found that our Individual Email Results does not include single sends emails, so we get different kpis about our sendings when we connect this object with a tool like PowerBI, than the Salesforce Reports themselves.

We checked than all the checkboxes involved are ok, but still we don´t see them. Why? Does this object only emails in includes journeys?

Answer (score 2):

You'll only get IER's created in Salesforce if your Send is one of the following:

- Guided Send to a Salesforce Report
- Guided Send to a Salesforce Campaign
- Journey Builder Send
- Triggered Sends using Salesforce Data Extension folder
- Salesforce Report/Campaign Import Send
- Manual Data Extension created (or moved to) Salesforce Data Extension folder

In all scenarios your SubscriberKey needs to be 18-digit LeadID/ContactID.

Also do note it can take over an hour for the IER's to be created in Salesforce.

In your scenario I'm assuming you were doing Email Sends to regular Data Extensions, so next time move your target Data Extension to the Salesforce Data Extension folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. We checked all the things you said, and don't understand where the single sends are included. As single sends I mean, one shot email, to a DE in Salesforce, directly from de email editing. No journey involved.

Comment: Yep. The DE must be located in the Salesforce Data Extensions folder.